# Spring MVC: Reject request coming from other domain/web pages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring web application. I have some GET & POST request mapper in spring controller. How can i restrict my appliation to accept request making from my site pages only.

i.e if it gets request `/insert` from `example.com` pages it should accept this but if it get any request other than `www.example.com` it should reject. e.g any request from `www.xyz.com` `localhost:8084` should be rejected.

I want to restrict anyone from making GET POST request to my app except if it is from my own domain page.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor`. Implement the logic to check the domain of request in  [preHandle](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#preHandle-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-) method via [getRequestURL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) API.